# Save formset in Django returns None model

Tags: django, django-forms

I've a problem with my formset. When I submit the formset, the models are not saved and displayed as None. I don't understand why, can somebody light me ?

There is no problem in the template nor the urls.py. I get this within my log console:
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB01k.png)

Here is my code:

```
// views.py
def classroom_call_the_roll(request, class_id):
  classroom = Classroom.objects.get(pk=class_id)
  students = classroom.students.all()
  queryset = Attendance.objects.none()

  AttendanceFormset = modelformset_factory(
      model=Attendance,
      form=AttendanceForm,
      can_delete=False,
      extra=len(students)
  )

  if request.method == 'POST':
      formset = AttendanceFormset(
          request.POST,
          queryset=queryset,
          initial=[{'student': student} for student in students]
      )
      for form in formset.forms:
          instance = form.save(commit=False)
          print(instance)
  else:
      formset = AttendanceFormset(
          queryset=queryset,
          initial=[{'student': student} for student in students]
      )

  return render(
      request,
      'highschool/attendance/classroom_attendance_create.html',
      {
          'formset': formset
      }
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i see you have set `commit=False` in **form.save** call. If you do this, you have to save the instance yourself by calling

```
instance.save()
```

Comment: I've tried but it says "NOT NULL constraint failed: highschool_attendance.student_id", so I just forced the initial value in the save. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

You should save the model manually. To do that, you should add  `instance.save()`